# Elasticsearch: Not giving match

Tags: elasticsearch, substring, match, match-phrase

I want to perform both exact word match and partial word/sub string match. For example, if I search for `"test product"` then I should be able to find `"test"` and `"product"` related text in the result. I'm searching Elasticsearch with the below match query, which is not giving me the exact match, instead its giving some more irrelevant match.

I'm using Elasticsearch 6.3

My query for `GET /_search`:

```json
{ 
  "must": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "title:*test product*"
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result:

```json
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "67107104",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 0.6931471,
    "_source": {
      "title": "testing"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "67107104",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 0.6931471,
    "_source": {
      "title": "product good"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "67107104",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "3",
    "_score": 0.6931471,
    "_source": {
      "title": "sample"
    }
  }
]
```

Expected Search Result:

```json
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "67107104",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 0.6931471,
    "_source": {
      "title": "testing"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "67107104",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 0.6931471,
    "_source": {
      "title": "product good"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the search query above, you are searching in the `review` field, whereas in the search result you are getting data for `title` field

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "review": "testing"
}
{
  "review": "product good"
}
{
  "review": "sample"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "review": "test product"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
  {
    "_index": "67119314",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 0.2876821,
    "_source": {
      "review": "product good"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: @revathi can you please share some sample index data ? Please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: I want product and test related title data not sample